# How to escape \n (newline) when importing CSV into Postgres using \copy command?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, csv, escaping

I am trying to import data into my postgres table using \copy from a CSV file
The data is as follows:

```
1,2,"First Line \n Second Line", "Some other data"
```

My motive is to preserve '\n' while importing the data.

The following works:

```
insert into table (col1, col2, col3, col4) values (1, 2, E'First Line \n Second Line', 'Some other data')
```

But how do I achieve the same result using \copy command?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only thing you can escape in CSV is the field delimiter (`"` by default) which you escape by doubling it.

Line breaks cannot be escaped, and indeed it is not necessary, as you can just use a literal line break.

This is a single line in CSV:

```
1,2,"First Line
Second Line", "Some other data"
```

Comment: I was kind of afraid I'll have to do that in the end. :/
Just a little side help, how to I export Excel data to csv with newlines?

Comment: I would like to help, but I don't know Excel. You can always use `COPY ... FROM PROGRAM 'command'` and substitute a command that massages the CSV file for you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you have to modify your csv to backslash `\n` you want to preserve

```
b=# copy t from stdout;
Enter data to be copied followed by a newline.
End with a backslash and a period on a line by itself.
>> "First Line \n Second Line"
>> "First Line \\n Second Line"
>> \.
COPY 2
b=# select * from t;
              a
-----------------------------
 "First Line                +
  Second Line"
 "First Line \n Second Line"
(2 rows)
```